# Replacing characters in a string and returning in python

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm using Pycharm as the software tool to code in python.

These words are in a text format but they are supposed to return different outputs

```
word = "<p>Santa is fat</p>"
secondword = "Potato & Tomato"
thirdword = "Koala eats http://koala.org/ a lot</p>"
```

I want to replace each of the following "<" , ">" , "&"  **to**  "`&lt;`" , "`&gt;`" , "`&amp;`"

So the output should look like

```
outputword = "&lt;p&gt;Santa is fat&lt;/p&gt;"
outputsecondword = "Fish &amp; Chips"
outputthirdword = ""&lt;p&gt;Koala eats <a href='http://koala.org/'>http://koala.org/</a> a lot&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Notice that the third word is a URL.
I dont want to use the html library.
I'm a noob at Python so please provide me with simple solutions. I considered using lists but whenever I replace a character in the list, it doesn't change

Comment: Note that the HTML entities are `'&gt;'` and `'&lt;'`...

Comment: When you say "I considered using lists but whenever I replace a character in the list, it doesn't change", that doesn't explain what you tried well enough for anyone to explain what you did wrong. Maybe you were one typo away from getting it right; maybe you were totally on the wrong track—if you show us the code, we can tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the `html` library, you can do the replacements like this:

```
replacewith = {'<':'lt;', '>':'gt;'}
for w in replacewith:
        word = word.replace(w,replacewith[w])

In [407]: word
Out[407]: 'lt;pgt;Santa is fatlt;/pgt;'
```

Or, in one line:

```
 word.replace('<','lt;').replace('>','gt;')
```

#### Update:

You can move the code into a function and call it like this:

```
def replace_char(word, replacewith=replacewith):
    for w in replacewith:
            word = word.replace(w,replacewith[w])
    return word
```

Calling it with `word` like below will give you:

```
replace_char("<p>Santa is fat</p>")
Out[457]: 'lt;pgt;Santa is fatlt;/pgt;'
```

To get the second one to work, update the dictionary:

```
In [454]: replacewith.update({'Potato':'Fish', 'Tomato':'Chips', '&': '&amp;',})
In [455]: replace_char("Potato & Tomato", replacewith)
Out[455]: 'Fish &amp; Chips'
```

You can do the same for any new characters that may appear in other new strings in pretty much the same way. Your input `thirdword` is missing a `<p>` right at the beginning.

```
In [461]: replacewith.update({'http://koala.org/':'<a href="http://koala.org/">http://koala.org/</a>'})
In [463]: replace_char("Koala eats http://koala.org/ a lot</p>", replacewith)
Out[463]: 'Koala eats lt;a href="http://koala.org/"gt;http://koala.org/lt;/agt; a lotlt;/pgt;'
```

Comment: Why the `if w in word:` test? If that's supposed to be an optimization, all you're actually doing is forcing it to linearly search `word` twice instead of once…

Comment: Also, why `replacewith.get(w)` instead of just `replacewith[w]`?

Comment: Give me a moment, let me try this.

Comment: @abarnert  Thanks for the comment. Fixed both. Unintentional "typos", both.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, works like a charm! One more quick question what is this format of "replacewith" called?

Comment: It is a `dictionary` @Manu.

Comment: @Tichodroma If I recall, that was the tutorial that I told myself that I won't need. Thanks though.

Comment: Okay, in terms of html entities, if I am testing two strings, one mentioned above in the question and two is "Fish & Chips". If I add the '&' : '&amp;' to the dictionary and run the code, the first string doesn't pass either. The output turns out to be '&amplt;p&ampgt;Santa is fat&amplt;/p&ampgt;'  How can I modify this code?

Comment: Could you please add the inputs that you are passing and the subsequent output to your question ? Thanks.

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 8):

Python comes [with batteries included](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape):

```
import html

word = "<p>Santa is fat</p>"
print(html.escape(word))
```

Output:

```
&lt;p&gt;Santa is fat&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: Upvote for not answering what he asks, but what he wants/needs.

Comment: How would you do it without using the "import html"

Comment: You wouldn't. Use the libraries Python provides. And just in case your next question is how to parse HTML with regular expressions: you don't either.

Comment: Basic `replace` method:
`s = 'abcdef'`
`s = s.replace('e', 'g')`
`s`
`>> 'abcdgf'`

Comment: Would it be possible to ask for a solution using a basic replace?

Comment: What happens if I want to replace b to z and e to g in one go?

Comment: `s = s.replace('b', 'z').replace('e','g')`